# When does the conclusion of the Cauchy integral theorem fail?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am interested in a condition  when following theorem of Cauchy integral fails:
 let $U$ be an open subset of $C$ which is simply connected, let $f : U → C$ be a holomorphic function, and let $\!\,\gamma$ be a rectifiable path in $U$ whose start point is equal to its end point. Then

[image]

As I understand, first condition of failing this statement should be that  function should not be  holomorphic or  function that is  not  complex differentiable in a neighborhood of every point in its domain.also maybe   also $U$ subset if it is not connected, then this theorem may fail, what is also other conditions? thanks in advance

Comment: Hint:
$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z} = 2\pi i.$$

Comment: in statement ,i mean general definitions of such events

Comment: If A,B,C,... imply Z, then Z may fail only if A fails, or B fails, or C fails, or.... You stated the theorem clearly enough to discern what A,B,C,... are and how many they are by yourself. Just have more confidence in your logic abilities :). Of course, the full solution would also include counterexamples showing that neither of the conditions A,B,C... can be dropped.

Comment: i see so it means that  simple  subset is not connected or function is  not isomorphic or  end and start point of  path is not equal,like this one?>

Comment: @dato yes, but be a bit careful. Assuming non-holoporphic function, or non-simply connected $U$, or that $\gamma$ doesn't have end point equal to start point (or any two of those, or all three), it's still _possible_ to find functions which give zero integral over certain paths. When you assume any of the things above, what you lose isn't the _possibility_ that the integral evaluates to $0$, but the _guarantee_ that it does.

Comment: but if all these three fail or  even two of them,then what  happens?

Comment: If any condition or a set of conditions fail, it doesn't yet mean that the conclusion fails. It is the same as my phrase "If it is raining, I carry an umbrella with me" does not imply that if it is not raining, I don't (maybe it is sunny but I am just carrying the umbrella to a repair shop, or for whatever other reason). Most mathematical theorems are also one way (If ..., then...). When it is a two way theorem, it normally starts with "The following are equivalent:" or some other explicit phrase with the same meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conclusion of a theorem **may** fail if one of its hypotheses fails. In this case, if either

1. the domain is not simply-connected, or
2. the function is not holomorphic, or
3. the path is not closed

the integral **may** be nonzero. However, there is nothing that says it **has to be** nonzero, even if all 1-2-3 fail together. This is what fedja commented on:

> If any condition or a set of conditions fail, it doesn't yet mean that the conclusion fails. It is the same as my phrase "If it is raining, I carry an umbrella with me" does not imply that if it is not raining, I don't (maybe it is sunny but I am just carrying the umbrella to a repair shop, or for whatever other reason). Most mathematical theorems are also one way (If ..., then...). When it is a two way theorem, it normally starts with "The following are equivalent:" or some other explicit phrase with the same meaning.

If you are looking for a set of conditions to guarantee that the integral is nonzero, here is one: $f$ is holomorphic except for one simple pole, and $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve that separates the pole from the boundary of the domain of $f$. This is just a consequence of the Residue theorem.

But if the path $\gamma$ is not locally rectifiable, there is no obvious meaning of $\int_\gamma f$ at all. In this case the statement fails simply because we lack a definition of the integral over such path.

Comment: Another set of observations:  If the domain is not simply connected, then you can find a function holomorphic on the domain, and a closed path so that the integral is nonzero.  Just put poles in the holes.


If the path is not closed, you can find a holomorphic function so that the integral is nonzero.  For instance, the integral of the constant function $1$ will be nonzero in this case.

If the function is not holomorphic, there is no guarantee that you can find a closed path whose integral is zero.